# C++11 for_each passing multiple values

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following method:

```
CalculateThreshold(std::vector<double> &data, int thres)
{
  // include functionality 
}
```

I then have a vector of vectors which I want to iterate through using the `std::for_each` and I have tried to use the following:

```
std::for_each(
   std::begin(results),
   std::end(results), 
   std::bind2nd(std::mem_fun(&CalculateThres), 1));
```

But I keep getting the error message:

> note: candiditates are template std::mem_fun_t<_Ret, _Tp> std::mem_fun(_Ret (_Tp::*)())

Anyone have a suggestion to where I'm going wrong? To me, this should work!

Comment: Is `CalculateThres()` a member function or a free function?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Yes, it's a free function

Comment: Then why are you using `std::mem_fun`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 What do you suggest? Sorry

Comment: `bind2nd` is deprecated in C++11, as well as `mem_fun`. Use `std::bind` instead.

Comment: `std::function<type>(CalculateTres)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `std::bind`, there's no need for `std::mem_fun` (as explained in the comments).

```
std::for_each(
   std::begin(results),
   std::end(results), 
   std::bind(CalculateThres, std::placeholders::_1, 1));
```

---

Also, `bind1st` and `bind2nd` are deprecated, you should use [`bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) instead. Similarly, `mem_fun` is deprecated too, its replacement is [`mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn).

Answer (score 6):

Let's look at what the compiler tells more closely, especially that part:

```cpp
std::mem_fun_t<_Ret, _Tp> std::mem_fun(_Ret (_Tp::*)())
```

`_Ret (_Tp::*)()` represents a pointer to a member function. You tried to pass the free function `CalculateThreshold` so this won't work, the type does not match.

Also, [`std::mem_fun`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fun) and [`std::bind2nd`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind12) are deprecated in C++11.

---

You're using C++11, so you basically have three easy solutions :

- Use the for range loop :

  ```cpp
  for (auto && v : results)
      CalculateThreshold(v, 1);
  ```
- Use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) with [`std::foreach`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) :

  ```cpp
  std::foreach(std::begin(results), std::end(results),
               std::bind(CalculateThreshold, std::placeholders::_1, 1));
  ```
- Use a lambda with [`std::foreach`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) :

  ```cpp
  std::foreach(std::begin(results), std::end(results),
               [](std::vector<double> & data) { CalculateThreshold(data, 1); });
  ```

Comment: one of the perks of using a `lambda` instead of `bind` is that you must explicitly name the parameters passed to the `lambda` instead of using `std::placeholders`. In this case the named parameter `data` replaces `std::placeholders::_1`.

Comment: Also, the syntax is much verbose (could be reduced in C++14 though), that's why I moved this solution in third position. To me the ideal solution is the for range loop, which combine both readability and smaller code size.